# Simple python program

Tags: python

Bear with me, i'm extremely new to the world of programming. I'm trying to design a simple data entry/answer program for ICD-9 codes related to medical billing.

Example:

```
Enter ICD-9: "487.1"
Answer: "Influenza with respiratory manifestations"

Enter ICD-9 Code: "844.2"
Answer: "Cruciate Ligament Tear of Knee"
```

I sketched this out in a few minutes, but I have no idea how to get the program to read a range of numbers instead of just the one number. I'm also getting ValueErrors: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 844.2, so I used 844 just to test.

Filename: icd9wizard.py

```
number = 844
running = True

while running:
    guess = int(input('Enter ICD-9 Code: '))

    if guess == number:
        print('Cruciate Ligament Tear of Knee')
    elif guess < number:
        print('Invalid entry')
    else:
        print('Invalid entry')
```

I know it's basic.. I just need an arrow pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "a range of numbers"? Is that something the user would input? If so, can you give an example of the sort of input the user would see and the desired result?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the responses you got, it's conventional to click the "check mark" next to the up-down vote button, so future searchers know which answer was most useful in answering your question.

Comment: My first thought would be not to treat the numbers as numeric and do string matches, after all, that's what you need -- an exact string match on the digits.  Their numerical order isn't important.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, the `int` data type can hold only whole integers, with no fractional part. For your application, since you won't be doing any actual *arithmetic* with the entered numbers, it's probably best to keep them as a string. So don't call `int` at all:

```
number = "844"

guess = input('Enter ICD-9 Code')
```

Notice how I changed `number` so that `"844"` appears in quotes. This means it could contain any character values, such as `"844.2"` or `"fred"`.

There is another data type called `float` that holds floating point values (numbers with fractional parts). However, this type is not suitable for your application because you're not going to do calculations with these numbers.

Comment: I agree, if you're not going to do any numeric computation, keep it as a string, for safety concerns.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a predefined set of numbers that you'd like to use, you can test for inclusion in a dictionary:

```
good_numbers = {"487.1": "Influenza with respiratory manifestations",
                "844.2": "Cruciate Ligament Tear of Knee",
                "133.7": "Being awesome at code"}
running = True

while running:
    guess = raw_input('Enter ICD-9 Code: ')

    if guess in good_numbers:
        print good_numbers[guess]
    else:
        print('Invalid entry')
```

Comment: +1 Good relevant example. Note that this example also uses strings to index the dictionary, which prevents the above confusion of type-casting.

Comment: Just a quick note - I edited my answer to work on Python 2.7.  This is just to disambiguate - you should still use `input` in Python 3, but `input` in 2.7 forces an `eval`, which makes `guess` a `float`.

Comment: Shouldn't you set `running = False` when you're done with the loop? Better yet, just get rid of that useless variable and `break` when you're done. Better yet, use exception handling as I did below.

Comment: In the spirit of minimal changes from the question, I'll stick with my answer, but I agree with your point, @machineyearning.  I got the impression that the posted question was a minimal example, and that `running` was being used elsewhere, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the `ValueError` by using `float()` instead of `int()`. An `int` is incapable of storing non-integers, i.e. numbers with values after the decimal point.

As for the rest of your question, you should think about using a `dictionary` (see the python documentation) with the ICD-9 codes as the keys and the answer/description as the values. This way you can put in a ton of codes and descriptions without having to use a giant block of `if` and `elif`. Consider filling this `dictionary` by reading in a file or something.

For example (once you have filled the dictonary):

```
number = 844.2
running = True

while running:
    guess = float(input('Enter ICD-9 Code: '))

    if guess in icd_9_dict.keys():
        print(icd_9_dict[guess])
    else:
        print('Invalid entry')
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast it to float() instead of int(). After you convert to float, you can get the integer part with int().

```
s = "100.3"
f = float(s) # 100.3
i = int(f) # 100
```

To read a range of values, you can do something like this:

```
s = input("Enter some values separated by space: ")
a = [float(value) for value in s.split(" ")] # array of floats
```

If you want N values, you can use a loop:

```
for i in range(N):
    s = input("Enter a value: ")
    # do something with this value
```

Your question is not clear, please improve it if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `input()` which tries to interpret the value given by the user (and can pose some security problems). Prefer `raw_input()` which always return a string. Then you can compare strings instead of numbers.

A Python dictionary is also a nice structure for what you are trying to build.

Comment: Looks like it is Python 3 (print is a function), so input() is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `844.2` is `float`, not `int` :)

For range of numbers - you mean like this?:

```
487.1 456.4 654.7
```

Than use `split(' ')` on your input. Use `raw_input` to always get whole line as a string, than you can do with it whatever you can do with strings.

**edit** as noted in other answers - if this codes has nothing to do with numbers (beside digits in them;] ) - leave them as strings.

Comment: Thanks to @gurney alex for note on `input` vs `raw_input` :)

Comment: He wants to be able to do direct comparisons to ICD9s.  He may be better off using decimal or even leaving them as strings, since those will be more literal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to put it out there that it's always better to ask for forgiveness than to ask permission. This is a python best practice, which may not be relevant to you as a beginning programmer, but it's good to get started on the right foot.

`try` just says "try to do the following stuff" and `except` says "if there was one of the following errors when you tried to do the above stuff, do this stuff instead". You can tell that `KeyError` is the right error to put here if you try to access your dictionary with an invalid key (try it yourself in the interactive interpreter, it will always list the exception) just like you were getting `ValueError` exceptions before:

```
good_numbers = {"487.1": "Influenza with respiratory manifestations",
            "844.2": "Cruciate Ligament Tear of Knee",
            "133.7": "Being awesome at code"}

while True:
    try:
        guess = input('Enter ICD-9 Code: ')
        print(good_numbers[guess])
        break
    except KeyError:
        print('Invalid entry')
        continue
```

Oh and just to mention also that `break` says to quit looping out of the inner-most loop and `continue` says to go back to the beginning of aforementioned loop.

> ```
> Enter ICD-9 Code: asd
> Invalid entry
> Enter ICD-9 Code: 487.1
> Influenza with respiratory manifestations
> >>>
> ```

Now just to point you in the right direction, you might be wanting to read input from a file; in this case, you're going to want to investigate the `open` command. To parse the input you can probably use `split` or something:

```
med_codes = open('IDC-9-2011.txt', 'r')
code_list = med_codes.read().split()
```

Then you can feed your codes into your dicitonary one at a time like:

```
for code in code_list:
    try:
        print (good_numbers[guess])
    except KeyError:
        print ( code, 'is an invalid IDC-9 code')
```

I think the main advantage here is that you know that you have some finite input, so you don't have to mess around with `while` loops and `running` counters or anything.

Oh yeah and remember to close your file when done!

```
med_codes.close()
```

Comment: Thanks - this is good. I took out the break and inserted continue to keep the program running.

Comment: Yeah, just to note, if you have an infinite loop with no break condition you can exit your program by pressing `Ctrl+c`

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of results indexed by the values you're looking for like:

```
ICDCODES = { "487.1": "Influenza with respiratory manifestations",
             "844.2": "Cruciate Ligament Tear of Knee" }
```

Then just compare and match:

```
print ICDCODES[input('Enter ICD-9 Code: ')]
```